# How to get text inside another element in li list - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, arrays

I have a **li** tag that contain **p** tag, inside **p** contain some **span** tag

I want to get the text of the **"role"** in
`<span class="tag">{{role}}</span>`

I'm trying

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('ul[data-tag="userJoinedList"] li')).forEach(function(element) {
        console.log(element.innerHTML)
}
```

```
<ul data-tag="userJoinedList">
    {{#users}}
       <li class="users">
           <p>
              <span class="users">{{username}}</span> 
              <span class="tag">{{role}}</span>
           </p>
       </li>
    {{/users}}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use a selector?

```js
document.querySelectorAll('ul[data-tag="userJoinedList"] li p span.tag')
    .forEach(function(element) { 
        console.log(element.innerHTML)
    }
)
```

Comment: Oh thank, it work, btw i'm beginner at Javascript

Comment: @KhánhTrầnQuốc It's ok, don't worry. We've all been beginners :D